# Query to find the stock

Tags: sql, ms-access

## **How To find the stock..?**

I have a table "Transactions" in which there are fields like ProductID(int), TransactionType(boolean), Qty(int)..

While we are purchasing, TransactionType is True,
And while we are Selling, TransactionType is False..

```
Id          Type          Qty  
1           true          3  
1           true          9  
1           False         2
```

If I buyed 12 qty of productId 1,
and Sold 2 Qty of productId 1,
then How can I get the stock remaining ...?

Comment: It is very hard to understand your question. What does the last paragraph have to do with the table above?

Answer (score 1):

```
select ProductID,
       sum(iif(TransactionType = 1, Qty, -Qty)) as total
from Transactions
group by ProductID
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
SELECT ProductId,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TransactionType = 1 THEN Qty ELSE -Qty END)
FROM Transactions
GROUP BY ProductId
```

Answer (score 0):

You calculate the sum, but instead of summing Qty, you need a case statement to interpret Qty as positive or negative:

```
select id, sum(Qty * case when type = 'true' then 1 else -1 end) as sum_qty
from transactions
group by id;
```